# IN Jquery , how do I go up a parent node?

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I just want to go up a parent node, so I can do a .find inside that parent node.

In a sense, I want to .find a sister.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('el').siblings('li');
```

or

```
$('el').parent().find('li');
```

Answer (score 0):

To traverse to a closest possible parent node

```
$('.someclassname').closest('.parentclassname')
```

And to find a node inside that

```
$('.someclassname').closest('.parentclassname').find('.findwhatever')
```

If the node you are finding is on same level of your current node
say

```
<div class="testcls">
  <p class="child1">child1</p>
  <p>child2</p>
</div>
```

In above child2 is sibling of child1 so you can find such siblings using

```
$('child1').siblings();
```